# Center align the actionsheet text and icons

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3, bottom-sheet

I am trying to centre align the text and icons in action sheet in ionic 3,In the list view its by default aligned to the left.
here is my code:

```js
    buttons: [
      { text: 'Delete', role: 'destructive' },
      { text: 'Share' },
      { text: 'Play' },
      { text: 'Favorite' },
      { text: 'Cancel', role: 'cancel' }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your custom css class to the buttons. For example:

```css
.center {
   text-align: center; 
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Then add this css class to your code like this:

```
buttons: [
      { text: 'Cancel', 
        role: 'cancel',
        cssClass: 'center'
       }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a custom class to your buttons.

For instance:

```
.customCenter {
     display: flex;    
     align-items: center;    
     justify-content: center; 
 }

{ text: 'Delete', role: 'destructive', class: 'customCenter' },
```